# Running an event every specified milliseconds in Python using threads

Tags: python

I have a function that basically adds two numbers, n number of times.

Now I want to create a timer_tick like event as in VB and record certain stuff while this code is running ... Something like

```
Thread.Start
CODE TO RUN
Thread.Stop

Thead_Action
Print "HI"
```

So basically during the calculation, every few seconds it will print hi, at the same time while the calculation is going on..

In short I want a timer_tick event that can be enabled or disabled.

I hope I can get some quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
import threading
def timeTick():
    #do your calculation here
    print "Hi"
    threading.Timer(10.0, timeTick).start() #execute this function every 10 seconds

timeTick()
```

You could find Timer documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: FOllowing your code this is what i wrote. But it only prints once!!

i want to keep printing till the function TEST OR FROM A SPECIFIC START TO END TIME

import threading
import time

def timeTick():
    #do your calculation here
    print "Hi"


def TEST():
   threading.Timer(0.001, timeTick).start() #execute this function every 10 seconds
   n=1000000
   x=1
   y=1
   start = time.clock()
   for i in range(0, n):
            r=x+y
   elapsed = 1000*(time.clock() - start)


TEST()